# How to encode a single string in python

Tags: python-2.7, urlencode

What I want to do is:

I have a directory name and file name. I want to add them to a URL and make a URL call. Lets say the directory is

```
D:/somedir/userdata/scripts
```

and the file name is myscript.txt

I want to add these as parameters to URL call but I want to encode them separately and not as key value pair. What I want is a function which can take input like:

```
D:/somedir/userdata/scripts
```

and return output like:

```
D%3A%2Fsomedir%2Fuserdata%2Fscripts
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote_plus('D:/somedir/userdata/scripts')
'D%3A%2Fsomedir%2Fuserdata%2Fscripts'
```

In Python 2:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote_plus('D:/somedir/userdata/scripts')
'D%3A%2Fsomedir%2Fuserdata%2Fscripts'
```